# WordPress Кэширование страниц, и обход кэширования для части страницы

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Использую W3 total для кэша страниц, установлен Woocommerce.

Страницы кэшируются и для гостей и для залогиненых пользователей, соответственно кэшируется и форма для отправки комментария к товару, для авторизованных пользователей форма имеет меньше полей, в итоге форма отображается не всегда корректно.

Скажите как решаются подобного рода проблемы в Wordpress?

С кэшированием фрагментов у меня есть догадки как это сделать, но скорее всего есть и другие варианты? Можно ли сделать разный кэш для гостей и для залогиненных пользователей...

Та же проблема и в комментариях к постам и т.п, буду благодарен за ссылку на материал, где решается такая задача.

Comment: W3TC, насколько я знаю, сбрасывает кеши страниц/комментариев при обновлении.  Возможно, у вас нестандартно названы формы комментариев. С кешированием пользователей - там есть настройка на `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_pgcache_cookiegroups`. Так же можно добавить  свои фрагменты.

Comment: Кеш сбрасывает при обновлении, с этим все в порядке, проблема в кеше формы до написания комментария. А вот cookiegroups, думаю это то что надо!!! Спасибо